# shopify scraper returning values with html elements

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, shopify

This Shopify scraper is returning the HTML elements with the body because it supports HTML formatting. How would I return values to the CSV without the HTML elements?

```
'body': str(product['body_html'])
```

Example of what's being returned to a CSV:

```
<p><span>These seasonal and spiced cookies will warm any Fall day. Gluten-free and allergy-friendly, enjoy sweet and�soft-baked cookies full of everything you want in a snack and nothing you don't.�</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML parser, for example `beautifulsoup` to string all tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text_with_html = '''<p><span>These seasonal and spiced cookies will warm any Fall day. Gluten-free and allergy-friendly, enjoy sweet and�soft-baked cookies full of everything you want in a snack and nothing you don't.�</span></p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text_with_html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
These seasonal and spiced cookies will warm any Fall day. Gluten-free and allergy-friendly, enjoy sweet and�soft-baked cookies full of everything you want in a snack and nothing you don't.�
```